# Strange performance degradation when using a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a nano AWS server running MySQL 5.5 for testing purposes. So, keep in mind that the server has limited resources (RAM, CPU, ...).

I have a table called "`gpslocations`". There is a primary index on its primary key "`GPSLocationID`". There is another secondary index on one of its fields "`userID`". The table has ***6583 records***.

When I run this query:

```
select * from gpslocations where GPSLocationID in (select max(GPSLocationID) from gpslocations where userID in (1,9) group by userID);
```

I get two rows and it takes a lot of time:

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| GPSLocationID | lastUpdate          | latitude   | longitude | phoneNumber                          | userID | sessionID                            | speed | direction | distance | gpsTime             | locationMethod | accuracy | extraInfo | eventType |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|          4107 | 2018-09-25 16:38:44 | 58.7641435 | 7.4868510 | e5d6fdff-9afe-44bb-a53a-3b454b12c9c6 |      9 | 77385f89-6b72-4b9e-b937-d2927959e0bd |     0 |         0 |      2.9 | 2018-09-25 18:38:43 | fused          |      455 | 0         | android   |
|          9822 | 2018-10-22 10:29:43 | 58.7794353 | 7.1952995 | 5240853e-2c36-4563-9dc3-238039de411e |      1 | 1fcad5af-c6ef-4bda-8fb2-d6e5688cf08a |     0 |         0 |    185.6 | 2018-10-22 12:29:41 | fused          |      129 | 0         | android   |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (14.96 sec)
```

When I just execute the inner select:

```
select max(GPSLocationID) from gpslocations where userID in (1,9) group by userID;
```

I get two values very fast:

```
+--------------------+
| max(GPSLocationID) |
+--------------------+
|               9822 |
|               4107 |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I take these two values and write them manually in the outer select:

```
select * from gpslocations where GPSLocationID in (9822,4107);
```

I get exactly the same result as the first query but in no time!

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| GPSLocationID | lastUpdate          | latitude   | longitude | phoneNumber                          | userID | sessionID                            | speed | direction | distance | gpsTime             | locationMethod | accuracy | extraInfo | eventType |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|          4107 | 2018-09-25 16:38:44 | 58.7641435 | 7.4868510 | e5d6fdff-9afe-44bb-a53a-3b454b12c9c6 |      9 | 77385f89-6b72-4b9e-b937-d2927959e0bd |     0 |         0 |      2.9 | 2018-09-25 18:38:43 | fused          |      455 | 0         | android   |
|          9822 | 2018-10-22 10:29:43 | 58.7794353 | 7.1952995 | 5240853e-2c36-4563-9dc3-238039de411e |      1 | 1fcad5af-c6ef-4bda-8fb2-d6e5688cf08a |     0 |         0 |    185.6 | 2018-10-22 12:29:41 | fused          |      129 | 0         | android   |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anybody explain this huge performance degradation when the two simple and fast queries are combined in one?

EDIT

Here is the output of `explain`:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+----------------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type  | possible_keys        | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                 |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+----------------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | gpslocations | ALL   | NULL                 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL | 6648 | Using where                           |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | gpslocations | range | userNameIndex,userID | userID | 5       | NULL |   11 | Using where; Using index for group-by |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+----------------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please include the query plans for these (via EXPLAIN) since they give a lot of information to what’s happening behind the curtain

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I added the result of `explain` to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` can have really bad optimization characteristics.  In your version of MySQL, the subquery is probably being run once for every row in `gsplocations`.  I think this performance problem was fixed in later versions.

I recommend using a correlated subquery instead:

```
select l.*
from gpslocations l
where l.GPSLocationID = (select max(l2.GPSLocationID)
                         from gpslocations l2
                         where l2.userID = l.userId
                        ) and
      l.userID in (1, 9);
```

And for this, you want an index on `gpslocations(userID, GPSLocationID)`.

Another alternative is the `join` approach:

```
select l.*
from gpslocations l join
     (select l2.userID, max(l2.GPSLocationID)
      from gpslocations l2
      where l2.userID in (1, 9)
     ) l2
     on l2.userID = l.userId
where l.userID in (1, 9);
```

Comment: After correcting `from gpslocations l` and creating the suggested index, the time drops to 6.9 seconds. Still strange.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi . . . In this case, a `join` is probably going to be the best approach.

Comment: You are not selecting `userID` in the inner `select` for the `on` condition to work.

Comment: Anyway, I think that you may be right about the `in` bad optimization characteristics. This is the only possible explanation for this strange behavior.

Comment: I upgraded to MySQL 5.7 and the problem no longer exists. So, it was a server internal optimization bug in MySQL 5.5.